# Not able to change bootstrap's css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm with a problem that I just can't change things on bootstrap's css. I've tried directly edit bootstrap and create another css for override, but no success on both. For example, I want to change navbar's background color but it doesn't work (curiously, it works on mobile), it still stay with the default color of bootstrap, which is black.

I'll let below a part of my code.

THIS IS THE CSS I'VE CREATED FOR OVERRIDING

```css
.navbar-inverse{
  background:#f46e42 !important;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Página de operações">
    <title> Operar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meucss.css">
  </head>
  <body>  
  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:history.back()"> Previous Page </a> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
             </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
     <li class="#"><a href="#"> About </a></li>
     <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Learn <b class="caret"> </b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Examples </li>
       <li><a href="#"> C++ </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Java </a></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Tutorials </li>
       <li><a href="#"> JavaScript</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Cobol </a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the link to bootstrap's css CDN, and changed the navigation element from "header" to "nav" per bootstraps documentation found here: [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar][1]

It looks as though Bootstrap natively uses a "nav" element as a container for the navigation. I tested this at desktop and tablet resolutions and it worked. I hope this helps.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background:#f46e42 !important;
    color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Página de operações">
    <title> Operar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meucss.css">
  </head>
  <body>  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:history.back()"> Previous Page </a> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
             </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
     <li class="#"><a href="#"> About </a></li>
     <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Learn <b class="caret"> </b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Examples </li>
       <li><a href="#"> C++ </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Java </a></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Tutorials </li>
       <li><a href="#"> JavaScript</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Cobol </a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

I updated the link to bootstrap's css CDN, and changed the navigation element from "header" to "nav" per bootstraps documentation found here: [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar][1]

It looks as though Bootstrap natively uses a "nav" element as a container for the navigation. I hope this helps

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background:#f46e42 !important;
    color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Página de operações">
    <title> Operar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meucss.css">
  </head>
  <body>  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:history.back()"> Previous Page </a> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
             </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
     <li class="#"><a href="#"> About </a></li>
     <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Learn <b class="caret"> </b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Examples </li>
       <li><a href="#"> C++ </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Java </a></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Tutorials </li>
       <li><a href="#"> JavaScript</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Cobol </a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the below mentioned css--

```
.navbar-inverse{
 background:#f46e42 !important;

   }
 .navbar-nav > li >a{
 color:blue !important;
 }
```

but usually using `!important` is not considered to be good practice.

So do it by assigning an id/class to the elements--

**working example**

```css
#nav{
  background:#f46e42;
   
}
#nav_links >li >a{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Página de operações">
    <title> Operar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:history.back()"> Previous Page </a> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
             </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul id="nav_links" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a class="" href="#"> Home </a></li>
     <li class="#"><a href="#"> About </a></li>
     <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Learn <b class="caret"> </b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Examples </li>
       <li><a href="#"> C++ </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Java </a></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Tutorials </li>
       <li><a href="#"> JavaScript</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Cobol </a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your bootstrap .class of the navbar try this

```css
.navbar-inverse-ok{
  background:#f46e42 !important;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Página de operações">
    <title> Operar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meucss.css">
  </head>
  <body>  
  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse-ok navbar-static-top" id="nav" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:history.back()"> Previous Page </a> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
             </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
     <li class="#"><a href="#"> About </a></li>
     <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Learn <b class="caret"> </b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Examples </li>
       <li><a href="#"> C++ </a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Java </a></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header"> Tutorials </li>
       <li><a href="#"> JavaScript</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> Cobol </a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try and swap both the  stylesheet line in the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33379766)